# Draw a chart in excel based on a string appearance

Tags: excel

I have an excel file that contains 6 different sheets and every sheet contains some cells that there's text value inside them.

Now, I want to draw a chart that shows how many times a string was revealed in a larger string.

As much as I could find in google search, excel will draw charts based on numeric values,

So, I need to know is there a way that draw a chart based on text with my criteria?

***Thanks in advance***

**UPDATE :**

Assume that I have values like this:

[image: sample image]

And I need to know how many times `a string` appeared in `B` cells for every program.

And What if program name was in another sheet and string col was in someone else.?

Answer (score 1):

No, Excel cannot chart anything based on text. You need numbers. In order to get these numbers you can apply different techniques, like formulas or VBA to analyse the text and produce the respective numbers. If you need more detail, provide more detail about your data.

Edit after question update: Consider this screenshot

[image]

the formula in C2 is

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$1,B2))*1
```

The table in columns F and G is a pivot table with "Program" dragged to the rows area and "found" dragged to the values area and set to sum. This table can be used for charting.

If the program and the string are in two different sheets, you can still use formulas to construct a data source for the pivot table.

Comment: well, as I'm newbie to excel, would you please describe more? how did you set `C2:C7` to have these values? I have more than 500 rows in `B*`, how can I write these formula for?  And how `F4:F6` find `programs`? sorry for basic issues...

Comment: It would be better if you gave detailed answer for help to a newbie instead of give some boring advice, but thanks again for your help. I'll try some where else...